# Getting results with joins

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a shop and I'm trying to export database results to a csv file. But I have problem with getting results from a database.
I want to export all order as follows :
[image]

Thus I want to show all shop no matter whether is anything ordered from that store. I tried with this query, but I get only 5 results and 5 is the number of order_details fields.

```
$rezOrders = mysqli_query(
    $kon, 
    "SELECT shops.naam AS shopNaam,
            shops.*,
            orders.*,
            orders.status AS orderSt,
            product_shop_tt.*, 
            order_details.*,
            producten.*
       FROM orders 
      INNER JOIN order_details ON order_details.order_id = orders.id
      RIGHT JOIN product_shop_tt ON order_details.product_shop_tt_id = product_shop_tt.id
       LEFT JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
      RIGHT JOIN shops ON shops.id = product_shop_tt.shop_id 
      WHERE orders.status = 1"
); 

$brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rezOrders);
while ($redOrders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezOrders)) {
    echo "Shop name : " . $redOrders["shopNaam"] . "<br />";
    echo "Number result : " . $brRez . "<br />";
}
```

Thus with this query there is no way to show all shops, because I get only shops which are connected with order_details table.

My tables from a database are :

[image]

How can I fix the query to get the right results?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the layout of the tables.  A SQL Fiddle also helps.  Also, it is almost never necessary to use `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` in the same query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did it.

Comment: some data normalization problems here Boky with `fanta | sprite` and multiple shop columns

Comment: @Drew That was only example what I want to get. It can be fanta, sprite..

Comment: so that column (in the db table not the query results) can contain `fanta, sprite` as opposed to `fanta | sprite` ? If so, same issue. Plus the shop columns (in the db ... if you have multiple show columns in the db)

Comment: No, in database I have table producten for fanta, cola and the rest. Thus every product is one field in the producten table.

Comment: you can put whatever you want in the csv. let's call that step 2 or 3. Right now I am concerned if you call it that ... that your database is not structured correctly (as a peer review)

Comment: so let's say 10 veteren db guys were to do a peer review and give advice on what is "correct". One guy says, sure, save data as `fresca, diet coke`. Not that you would need to heed their advice. There are many ways to save data. Some are just not a good flexible approach. And we haven't seen how you are saving your data, but making assumptions from query results that may be joining "correctly saved data" into sets that look denormalized